# Handbrake: How to batch convert videos including resize?

Tags: video, batch, handbrake

I am using the latest [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) v0.9.9. I would like to batch convert 200 video files from format 800x600 to 640x480. The problem is, if I add the videos to the Queue (clicking on >Source >Folder), and if I change the `Width` parameter of the first video to 640x480, I see that all other videos still have 800x600.

So I actually have to go through -each- video one by one and insert `Width: 640` manually.

Is there any way I can set up the format 640x480 for all videos at once?

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the *Profile* section on the right. Setup a profile with custom width. Add a folder to your queue, then select the profile from the right. If you go through all videos now (see dropdown), you notice that all videos will have the setting `Width: 640`.

Then click on the down-arrow "Add To Queue" and select "Add All", click "Start" and the batch processing starts.

Comment: Profiles will screw things up if the resize is larger than the current resolution. here it tries to convert all my 1920x1080 videos to 1700somethingx1080 because that is the resolution of my monitor

Comment: This one was a bit of a face slap, one needs to set the video size **when adding/saving** the preset; if not the size will always default to the source's, no matter the edits.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I converted all raw mts files from camera using handbrakecli from command line (here I used bash command line in mobaxterm)

First, I checked in handbreak GUI log file which options were used when I was convering single mts from GUI. Having this I created file with options (in example named 'opcyje') which I later used for batch processing.

```
[mobaxterm] ➤ ls *.mts

00139.MTS  00141.MTS  00143.MTS  00145.MTS  00147.MTS  00149.MTS  00151.MTS  00153.MTS
00140.MTS  00142.MTS  00144.MTS  00146.MTS  00148.MTS  00150.MTS  00152.MTS  00154.MTS

[mobaxterm] ➤ cat opcyje

 -i **${i}** -t 1 --angle 1 -c 1 -o **${i%.*}**.mp4 -f mp4  -w 1920 --crop 0:0:0:0 --loose-anamorphic  --modulus 2 -e x264 -q 20 --vfr -a 1 -E av_aac -6 dpl2 -R Auto -B 160 -D 0 --gain 0 --audio-fallback ac3 --encoder-preset=veryfast  --encoder-level="4.0"  --encoder-profile=main  --verbose=1

[mobaxterm] ➤ type HandBrakeCLI.exe

HandBrakeCLI.exe is hashed (/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Handbrake/HandBrakeCLI.exe)

[mobaxterm] ➤ for i in *.mts;do eval HandBrakeCLI.exe $(cat opcyje);done
```

It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**export queue as json and converte in to this and import**

```
const Results = exportedJson.map((val) => {
    const hms = val?.Statistics.ContentLength;
    var a = hms?.split(':');
    var seconds = +a[0] * 60 * 60 + +a[1] * 60 + +a[2];
    val.Task.PointToPointMode = 1;
    val.Task.StartPoint = 0;
    val.Task.EndPoint = seconds;
    return val;
  });
```

console.log(Results);

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to customize a new profile manually to make your all videos in queue with same settings.

Alternatively, if you think this is a bit complicated, you can try another program call AppGeeker converter - I use it all the time.

http://www.appgeeker.com

It has a "Apply to All" option on the interface you can use, just simply click it and you're off.

Answer (score -2):

Use http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/

I was also struggling with handbrake a lot, freemake has good enough user interface, at least did not have to google on how to do things unlike with handbrake.

And also it is **free!!!**